# Convert ascii character codes into letters in a string containing text and ascii codes in JS

Tags: javascript, dom

I am working on an HTML web page, and in the js, I read the end of the URL and place it in a div e.g. if the URL is

`http://example.com/file.html?postval=Hello, world!`

it should post "Hello, world!", unfortunately, it posts "Hello,%20world". how can I fix this?

Comment: Converting spaces to `%20` or `+` is correct behavior for posting.  A URL can't contain a space.  https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/  These characters should be correctly decoded on the remove side.  If they aren't, the remote code is in error.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher unfortunately, the code to bring the user to the site sends it with spaces and not %20 s or + s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use decodeURIComponent

```
var a = decodeURIComponent('Hello,%20world');

a = 'Hello, world!';
```